# fail to open system.install after transferring to debain

Tags: migrations, users

I am moving a completed Drupal site from the wamp in my windows system onto my virtualBox, which uses Debian system for this. Just to practice before I move everything onto the real linux server later.

Now I have imported the database successfully onto phpmyadmin. I have copy paste the site files onto the localhost directory. when I try to open the site from the localhost/MySite, it directly went to localhost/MySite/install.php and return a blank page. So I checked the error log, here is what I got:

```
[Fri Jul 26 15:13:07 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/MySite/modules/system/system.install' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/Mysite/includes/install.core.inc on line 241
[Fri Jul 26 15:13:53 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/MySite/modules/system/system.install' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/MySite/includes/install.core.inc on line 241
```

I don't understand the include_path bit, what is this route?

I have also checked the permission for both MySite directory and system.install file using ls -ld

I got this for the MySite direction:

```
drwxrwxrwx 9 root yikaiw 4096 Jul 26 14:22 /var/www/MySite
```

and this for the file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root yikaiw 112795 Jun 25 14:36 /var/www/Brompton/modules/system/system.install
```

I noticed the second date is weird, but I have no idea what is happening now.

Please help me! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you've copied and correctly set up permissions for DRUPAL_ROOT/modules/system/system.install. In fact, check the integrity of your entire Drupal install it's likely you have missing files or haven't set up the correct permissions

Comment: Thanks Clive, but I checked the permission on both the directory and system.install. it showed something like -rw-r--r-- 1 root yikaiw 112795 Jun 25 14:36 /...the directory.../, both root and yikaiw (my account) are there. Can you spot anything wrong? Thanks

Comment: Is your apache server user part of the "yikaiw" group (or equivalent)?

Comment: "www-data" is default apache group on debian distribution.

Comment: Clive, apache user is root, yikaiw is a new account.

Comment: Xio, I can see that from the output when I check the apache user, but I don't know what to do with it? Can you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Which way you are using to finding out what user Apache is running as?

Comment: this command: lsof -i

Comment: Clive, you are right, thank you. I think it is a time delay or cache, I tried several times and it just suddenly worked. Now I can access the front page, but I have a new problem and I should start a new topic. But thank you very much!